# VueJS and lodash, filtered array displays empty unless main array is utilized in template

Tags: vue.js, lodash, vuejs2

My mixin:

```js
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            charges: [],
            catCharges: [],
            offenses: ['Class I Offenses', 'Class II Offenses', 'Class III Offenses', 'Class IV Offense']
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getCharges() {
            axios.get('admin/charges').then((response) => {
                this.charges = response.data;
                for(let offense = 1; offense <= this.offenses.length; offense++) {
                    this.catCharges[offense - 1] = this.chargesAtOffense(offense);
                }
            });
        },
        chargesAtOffense(offense) {
            return _.filter(this.charges, { offense_level: offense });
        }
    },
    created() {
        this.getCharges();
    }
};
```

Fetching data works, the array 'charges' gets populated with the following:
[image]

After populating the array, I start looping over the offenses array and filter all 'charges' from the main array into the 'catCharges' array, so all offenses are split into 4 separated arrays in that array.

Chrome's developer tools shows the array just fine and the charges are properly filtered.
[image]

This is my component:

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>Total charges: {{charges.length}}</h1>
        <h1>Total offense categories: {{catCharges.length}}</h1>
        <div v-for="(charges, offenseIdx) in catCharges">
            {{charges}}
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

    import chargesMixin from '../mixins/chargesMixin';

    export default {
        mixins: [chargesMixin],
        data() {
            return {

            }
        },
        methods: {

        },
        computed: {

        },
        mounted() {
            console.log('Disciplinary Segregation mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

It uses the mixin provided above, and IT works and shows the catCharges array properly, HOWEVER when I remove the following line from the template:

```
<h1>Total charges: {{charges.length}}</h1>
```

The catCharges array is displayed as EMPTY, why do I need to use the charges array too along with the filtered array? This is driving me crazy.

I also tried the following method in the mixin which also causes the same issue:

```js
chargesAtOffense(offense) {
    var newCharges = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < this.charges.length; i++) {
        if(this.charges[i].offense_level != offense) continue;
        const cloned = _.clone(this.charges[i]);
        newCharges.push(cloned);
    }
    return newCharges;
}
```

Comment: Can you try using a different variable name in v-for and tell how it behaves? "<div v-for="(charges, offenseIdx) in catCharges">", don't use charges, use any other name and post what happens.

Comment: Its still the same. Even when I simply output the array 'catCharges'. I'm clueless really, but I did simply fix it by styling the h1 tag to display 'none' the actual charges array.  So the filtered array will work, however I'm still not sure why I have to use the main charges array in the template order for the filtered array to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your use case is linked to the reactivity system of VueJS.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

If you delete the line

`<h1>Total charges: {{charges.length}}</h1>`

you tell to VueJS to refresh your template only on `catCharges` get / set.

`catCharges` is an array, and so it's not as 'reactive' as a simple variable.

If you read precisely https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats, prefer use a `push` on your `catCharges` to explain correctly to Vue that your array has changed.

I'll try this code :

```
getCharges() {
  axios.get('admin/charges').then((response) => {
    this.charges = response.data;
    for(let offense = 1; offense <= this.offenses.length; offense++) {
      this.catCharges.push(this.chargesAtOffense(offense));
    }
  });
},
```

Hope this will solve your problem.